# How to make DPI Scaling lower than 100% in Windows 8.1

Tags: resolution, windows-8.1, dpi

There are a lot of articles with how to make older version of windows with DPI scaling under 100%.

But when I try those methods on Windows 8.1 it is automatically returning me to 100% dpi after restart or sign out.

Changing a DPI to less then 96 DPI (which is 100%) can be done with Windows 7 and 8.

But can it be done with Windows 8.1 ? Did anyone manage to do that ?

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a bit nit-picky, but DPI is not a percentage, its a measurement (dots per inch).  I think Windows defaults to 96 DPI usually.  Please try and be clear what you're wanting to change in your question.

Comment: check this it might help what you are trying to do http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-screen-text-larger-smaller#make-screen-text-larger-smaller=windows-7

Comment: no i mean DPI. You can make DPI less in Windows 7 and Windows 8 by changing LogPixels in Registry but that doesn't work for Windows 8.1 so i am asking for help how to do that in Windows 8.1

Comment: I know that 96 DPI is default but i want to change it to 86. That is possible with Windows 7 and Windows 8. I am looking for someone who have done that in Windows 8.1.

Comment: A better term might be Windows DPI Scaling.  I cannot find an official Microsoft term for this setting, but it is clear from Shakehar's link what the context is.

Comment: @heavyd pretty sure he is talking about [these DPI percentages](http://i.stack.imgur.com/F3ZoF.png), you get to it by clicking the circled item.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain You can get to that UI by checking the "Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays" - then the "Custom sizing options" link appears and gets you the ruler etc. - but it doesn't let you go < 100%.